# Play streaming sound in OpenTK?

Tags: c#, audio, opentk, streaming

What's the simplest way to make a sound stream from disk and play in OpenTK?

Comment: OpenTK is a graphics library. There's no built-in support for playing sounds. Try OpenAL.

Comment: @Byte56: OpenAL seems to be included in OpenTK. I'm just not sure where to begin with playing sounds using it. I can't find any simple examples in C#.

Comment: Did you try the [documentation](http://www.opentk.com/doc/audio)?

Comment: OpenAL being included means that you are still using it to stream audio as such, a streaming guide for OpenAL should be sufficient. http://benbritten.com/2010/05/04/streaming-in-openal/